# if i hashed both email and passwords can you please let me know how to login then in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have a user model what i have encrypted both email and passwords using bcrypt in nodejs.
what i want to do is to login the user please if someone share any example how to login kindly let me know then thanku.

Comment: ideally, you don't encrypt email, only passwords are encrypted

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same concept used for comparing hashed password using bcrypt.

Here is a sample code

```js
/**
   * @method hashString
   * @description Hashes a plain text string
   * @param {String} string - The plain text string to be hashed
   * @returns {string} The hash string
   */
  static hashString(string) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(string, 10);
  }

  /**
   * @method verifyHash
   * @description compares plain strings to hashed strings for authentication
   * @param {string} plainTextString - The plain text string to be verified
   * @param {string} hashedString - Stored hashed string to compare against
   * @returns {boolean} Booelean indicating success or failure
   */
  static verifyHash(plainTextString, hashedString) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(plainTextString, hashedString);
  }

// You can try this below

verifyHash(password, user.password))
verifyHash(email, user.email))
```

Comment: Thanks @martins but from where i get that user you used here verifyHash(password, user.password))
verifyHash(email, user.email))

Comment: The user.email or user.password should just be replaced with the actually email and password of the use that you are trying to compare. It could come from the request body while the user inputs his/her details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir, but one thing i just want to know that if i have verified the user with that how can i just fetch the user from db like on which basis i can fetch it bcz i had hashed both also if both email and password matched how can i fetch that record of the user . please provide some sample if you can. thanku.

Comment: Firstly you should not be hashing the email. Its unusual.

Regarding the password, use the bcrypt.compare(). Try looking up on bcrypt documentation its quite straight forward. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: Sir my question was hashing both email and password , then how can i authenticate a user or get user's information.